# SQL Query - Excel Formula Conversion

Tags: sql

Excel Formula Grabs Date and if it is Less then 90 Days remaining States Warning, if it is  today or more it is In Warranty and if it is Past Today it is Expired.

Formula:

```
=IF(J2="","",IF(TODAY()-J2>0,"Expired",IF(J2-TODAY()<=90,"Warning","In Warranty")))
```

J Column is End Date Column for Warranty... Example 03/02/2015 (Which has 84 Days left so it is in Warning Status)

I want to convert this to SQL Query:  This is what I have so far, but it is not working properly.

```
DECLARE @TODAY smalldatetime = getdate()

CASE
    WHEN d.End_Date IS NULL THEN 'No Warranty Information Available'
    WHEN Datediff(DAY, @TODAY, d.End_Date) <90 THEN 'Warning'
    WHEN Datediff(DAY, @TODAY, d.End_Date) > 1 THEN 'In Warranty'
    WHEN Datediff(DAY, @TODAY, d.End_Date) = 0 THEN 'Expired'
END AS [Warranty Status],
```

This is not returning properly can someone assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like your Excel formula, each step is evaluated and if the condition is met, that is the value printed out and the statement ends.

So if there were, for example, 0 days left, your CASE statement will evaluate

`datediff(DAY, @TODAY, d.End_date) < 90`

which is TRUE so it will print out "Warning" rather than "Expired" as you intend.

So you want to check your statements in the correct order:

```
DECLARE @TODAY smalldatetime = getdate()

CASE
    WHEN d.End_Date IS NULL THEN 'No Warranty Information Available'
    WHEN Datediff(DAY, @TODAY, d.End_Date) <= 0 THEN 'Expired'
    WHEN Datediff(DAY, @TODAY, d.End_Date) <90 THEN 'Warning'
    ELSE 'In Warranty'
END AS [Warranty Status],
```

Comment: You might want to change the "expired" condition to >=.   Otherwise, the day after the warranty expires it will return "In Warranty"

Comment: OP's excel formula also says `<=90` but their sql says only `<90`  Not sure which is correct, but probably the former.

Comment: What about Conditional Formatting these results?  In Warranty = Green, Warning = Yellow, Expired = Red

Comment: SQL doesn't contain any native formatting, where are you displaying the results of the query?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what answer you're seeing, but from the SQL clause, it looks like 'Expired' will never occur because zero is also <90. Move the check for zero above the warning check, and it should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8a8379/2)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE d
    ([End_Date] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO d
    ([End_Date])
VALUES
    ('2015-03-02 00:00:00'),
    ('2014-12-07 00:00:00'),
    ('2014-12-08 00:00:00'),
    ('2015-12-08 00:00:00')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
DECLARE @TODAY smalldatetime = getdate()

SELECT
CASE
    WHEN d.End_Date IS NULL THEN 'No Warranty Information Available'
    WHEN Datediff(DAY, d.End_Date, @TODAY) > 0 THEN 'Expired'
    WHEN Datediff(DAY, @TODAY, d.End_Date) <= 90 THEN 'Warning'
    ELSE 'In Warranty'
END AS [Warranty Status]
FROM d
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8a8379/2/0)**:

```
| WARRANTY STATUS |
|-----------------|
|         Warning |
|         Expired |
|         Warning |
|     In Warranty |
```